# Model value not being set on return from View to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a boolean model variable who's value is supposed to be set to TRUE in order to perform a process on return back into the Controller.

It works **absolutely fine** on my local machine, but not on the remote web server.

Can somebody PLEASE inform me what I am missing? Below is the "proof of the pudding": The boolean value in quesion is "**ShouldGeneratePdf**";

**MODEL:**

```
namespace PDFConverterModel.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
    {
        public ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors()
        {
            Templates = new List<PDFTemplate>(); 
            Guarantors = new List<tGuarantor>(); 
        } 

        public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
        public List<PDFTemplate> Templates { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGuarantorId { get; set; }
        public List<tGuarantor> Guarantors { get; set; }

        public string LoanId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public bool isRepeat { get; set; }
        public string ddlDept { get; set; }
        public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
        public string LoanTypeId { get; set; }
        public string LoanType { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }
        public string ErrorT { get; set; }
        public string ErrorG { get; set; }
        public bool ShowGeneratePDFBtn { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldGeneratePdf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MasterPage**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.blueopal.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.913/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>BHG :: PDF Service Generator</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**View**:

```
@model PDFConverterModel.ViewModels.ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{ 
    <table style="width: 1000px">

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ShouldGeneratePdf)

        <tr>
            <td>
                <img alt="BHG Logo" src="~/Images/logo.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBox()
                  .Placeholder("Enter Loan Id")
                  .Name("LoanId")
                  .Format("{0:#######}")
                  .Value(Convert.ToInt32(Model.LoanId))
                )
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Loan Type: ")
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.LoanType)
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="ddlDept">Department:</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => Model.ddlDept)
                            .Name("ddlDept")
                            .DataTextField("DepartmentName")
                            .DataValueField("DepartmentID")
                            .Events(e => e.Change("Refresh"))
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetDepartments", "Home");
                                });
                            })
                            .Value(Model.ddlDept.ToString())
                    )
            </td>
        </tr>

        @if (Model.ShowGeneratePDFBtn == true)
        {
            if (Model.ErrorT == string.Empty)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <u><b>@Html.Label("Templates:")</b></u>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Templates.Count; i++)
                {  
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Templates[i].IsChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Templates[i].TemplateId)
                    </td> 
                }

            </tr>
            }
            else
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ErrorT)</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

            if (Model.ErrorG == string.Empty)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <u><b>@Html.Label("Guarantors:")</b></u>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guarantors.Count; i++)
                { 
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Guarantors[i].isChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Guarantors[i].GuarantorFirstName)&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Guarantors[i].GuarantorLastName)
                    </td> 
                }

            </tr>
            }
            else
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ErrorG)</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="btnRefresh" value='Refresh' />
            </td>
            @if (Model.ShowGeneratePDFBtn == true)
            {
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="btnGeneratePDF" value='Generate PDF' />
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: red; font: bold">
                @Model.Error
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnRefresh').click(function () {
        Refresh();
    });

    function Refresh() {

        var LoanID = $("#LoanID").val();

        if (parseInt(LoanID) != 0) {
            $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(false)
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter a LoanId");
        }
    }

    //$(function () {
    //    //DOM loaded
    //    $('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
    //        DisableGeneratePDF();
    //        $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)
    //    });
    //});

    //function DisableGeneratePDF() {
    //    $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
    //    $('#btnRefresh').attr("disabled", true);
    //}


    $('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
        alert("inside click function");
        DisableGeneratePDF();
        $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)
        tof = $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val();
        alert("ShouldGeneratePdf set to " + tof);
    });

    function DisableGeneratePDF() {
        alert("begin DisableGeneratePDF function");
        $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#btnRefresh').attr("disabled", true);
        alert("end DisableGeneratePDF function");
    }

</script>
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessForm(string submitbutton, ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors model, FormCollection collection)

if ((submitbutton == "Refresh") || (submitbutton == null) && (model.ShouldGeneratePdf == false))
            {
}
else if ((submitbutton == "Generate PDF") || (model.ShouldGeneratePdf == true))
            {
}
```

The "Alerts" in the script above come out to exactly what they should be on the remote server. The last alert shows that the value of the bool variable is "true". However, **when I do page source views of the hidden variable, below is the result.**

**The values of the hidden variable when the page loads and when the last alert button finishes are as follows:**

**My local machine:**

**The remote machine:**

As you can see, the value on my machine is set to **true** when the process executes. However, on the remote machine, it is set to **false** where it then doesn't excute.

**Why isn't the value in the model being returned as TRUE on the remote machine?**

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a typo, but the line

```
$('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)
```

does not have the closing ;

```
$('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue is....

Using Fiddler, I was able to determine that the website runs just fine under FireFox (v16.0.2). I could see the value getting changed in Fiddler to true where it would execute the normal process.

For the latest version of Chrome, it did not work (v23.0.1271.84).

If using IE9, it automatically jumps into Compatability mode when going to the site. In IE9, if Compatability View is being used, it doesn't work. Once I changed from compatability View back to just IE9, it worked fine. Prior to IE9 (IE8 & IE7), did not work either.

How and when can these issues be fixed by Microsoft & Google?

Any suggestions in the meantime to work around this?

I unchecked the box under the Tools | compatability View Settings and unchecked the box that says "Display intranet sites in Compatability mode."

So, now when I go into IE, it automatically puts me into regular IE9 mode.

Anyone know of a similiar setting for Chorme?